# Azure Open AI - Add your Data not working

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I created a Azure Open AI resource in Azure, and then followed the steps to create a Azure Cognitive search resource and was able to successfully connect Search to My Azure SQL DB. I tested the search and it was returning the data it has indexed from my Sql db.
Then In the Azure AI studio, I set up Add your Data option successfully.
But in the chat, I don't see any results coming via my custom data, has anyone tried this? [image: No results]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have the same issue. The 'playground' AI seems utterly dumb. I've played around with the settings, clicked 'limit responses to your data content' on and off. Nothing seems to make much difference.

I uploaded an Uber 10K company filing, with a ton of financial information in it. I get the responses in the screenshot. It also seems to generally ignore multiple files, and you can only occaisionally get a semi sensible answer from the first file you upload.

Very disappointing indeed. But then again, it is Microsoft.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple of simple testings with this and the best results started coming when I put a more detailed system message. For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB8fX.png)

Index is created over a sql view that returns **salesorderId**, **CustomerName**, **order_date**.
You can see is very, very simple, far away from real world scenarios but I think it is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to do the same, but i keep getting a message that model did not find any related info. May I know the configuration steps that you used?

Answer (score 0):

Yes There is known issue in UI, You can use the following [repo](https://github.com/akshata29/chatpdf) to Chat and Ask on your own data. Accelerator to quickly upload your own enterprise data and use OpenAI services to chat to that uploaded data and ask questions.

Comment: Holy smokes, that's not the easiest app to install. Any idea when the Azure Chat Service will actually work correctly?

Comment: once the fix rolled out for UI, will update on the same.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenAI studio is a development tool and environment. It does NOT maintain state across sessions. If you want to use "on your data" you should configure the data elements, and deploy the web app for use within their enterprise. once that is done their development tasks are complete, and the webapp is deployed. when they leave the studio and come back, it will have no memory of their previous activities, nor will it retain any configurations they have created.

Comment: That's totally fine, but the OpenAI studio literally produces no answers, at all. It always says "I couldn't find any information....", a la the screenshots everyone is posting.